# Callback to prevent looping before completion of ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynccallback

I have read countless examples of similar posts calling for help and also explanations of the theory behind callbacks, but I just can't grasp it. I have gotten to the stage where I'd rather find a solution for my particular scenario and move on even if I don't really understand 'why/how' it works. 
I have an ajax call that needs to loop through and need to find a way to prevent the next call before the previous has completed. Could you suggest how I might use a callback or other method to make this happen.

Here's the code (which works, but doesn't run the ajax calls 1-by-1 so I'm getting memory errors and page crashes). The function that runs is quite intensive and can take up to 20 seconds (but as little as 1 second)

```
function returnAjax(startLoc,startRow)
{
        var url='index.php?option=com_productfinderrtw&format=raw&task=goThroughProcess';
        var data = 'startloc='+startLoc+'&starttour='+startRow;
                            var request = new Request({
                            url: url,
                            method:'get',
                            data: data,
                            onSuccess: function(responseText){
    document.getElementById('fields-container').innerHTML= responseText;  
//I realise this is where on-success code cneeds to go- is this where the callback belongs? 
                            }
                            }).send();

}

function iterator (startLoc,startRow) {
    if (startRow <20)
        {
        startRow++;
        }
        else
        {
        startRow = 1;
        startLoc++;
        }
    return [startLoc, startRow];
}


function runRAA() {
    var startLoc = 0;
    var startRow = 1;

    while (startLoc < 47)
    {
    returnAjax(startLoc,startRow);
    $counter = iterator(startLoc,startRow);
        var newLoc = $counter[0];
        var newRow = $counter[1];

        startLoc = newLoc;
        startRow = newRow;
    }
}
```

`runRAA()` is the main function that runs on a button press. How can I rearrange this to make sure that returnAjax doesn't run until the previous time is completed?

Thanks in advance for this. I KNOW that similar questions have been asked, so I beg that you don't direct me to other explanations- chances are I've read them but just don't grasp the concept.

Cheers!

PS. I understand that the iterator() function needs to run only when the returnAjax() is complete also, as iterator() sets the new parameter values for each instance of the returnAjax() function

Comment: where is the new Request class defined ?

Answer (score 0):

Allow to pass a `callback` parameter that will be called when the ajax call is completed.

```
function returnAjax(startLoc, startRow, callback) {
    //...
    onSuccess: function(responseText) {
        document.getElementById('fields-container').innerHTML= responseText;
        if (callback) {
            callback.apply(this, arguments); //call the callback
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
 function runRAA(startLoc, startRow) {
        startLoc =  startLoc || 0;
        startRow = startRow || 1;

        if (startLoc < 47) {
            returnAjax(startLoc, startRow, function (responseText) {
                var counter = iterator(startLoc, startRow);

                //do something with the response

                //perform the next ajax request
                runRAA(counter[0], counter[1]);

            }));
        }
    }

    runRAA(); //start the process
```